# conditional searching using perl

Tags: perl

Here is my input file:

```
Test1
{
 abc
 jkl
 mno
 search_text
 pqr
}
Test2
{
 stu
 vwx
}
Test3
{
 yza
 search_text
 bcd
}
```

Problem: print the test name (Test1, Test2, Test3 etc.) if there exists "search_text" inbetween the curly braces of that test.

Output expected from given in put file:

```
Test1
Test3
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site. I had tried stuff but didn't post it. Will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner does what you need:

```
perl -lne'
BEGIN { $/ = "}" } 
if ( /search_text/ ) { 
    $match = $.==1 ? (split "\n")[0] : (split "\n")[1]; 
    print $match; 
}' file
Test1
Test3
```

#### Explanation:

- `-l`: Chomps the newline while processing and places it back during print.
- `-n`: Creates an implicit `while(<>) { ... }` loop to process each line.
- `-e`: Tells the `perl` interpreter to execute the code that follows it.
- `$/`: In the `BEGIN` block we set the input field separator to `}` instead of default newline.
- Since our working line has effectively turned in to chunks of line separated by `}` we test if the line contains our `search_text`. If it does, we put the desired text by splitting the line on newlines and if it is our first line we capture the first split else we capture the second split and print the text.